# How can i make the alert pop-up when the count is 0 and i have no previous entries?

Tags: javascript

this is the function:

```
function reset() {
  if (count > 0 || saveEl != "Previous entries:") {
    count = 0;
    countEl.textContent = count;
    saveEl.textContent = "Previous entries:";
    console.log("the count has been resetted");
  } else {
    alert("You can't reset, number must be >0");
  }
}
```

in this case it reset always without alert, but i want to make the alert pop-up only when the count is 0 and there are no previous entries

Answer (score 0):

You could first check, if an alert should be raised, like so:

```
function reset() {
  if (count === 0 && saveEl.textContent !== "Previous entries:" {
    alert("You can't reset, number must be >0");
  } else {
    count = 0;
    countEl.textContent = count;
    saveEl.textContent = "Previous entries:";
    console.log("the count has been resetted");
  }
}
```

Edited - the message to check for is on `saveEl.textContext`. That was another error in the original code from the question.

Comment: didn't do the trick, thank you tho

Comment: @Dima - hope you spotted your error already, I updated my answer and now it should really work.